# Neuter Reactants: What do they do?

Tags: kinetics

So imagine a hypothetical chemical equation

$$
A + B \rightarrow C + B
$$

It is obvious from the equation that $B$ is not consumed during the reaction. If $B$ actively take part in the reaction, if it participates in the transition state and isn't just sitting there in the environment, I classify $B$ as a *Neuter Reactant*.

Under these defitions I would like to know:

**Is a Neuter Reactant always a Reaction Inhibitor or Catalyst?**

or are there instances of neuter reactants $B$ such that their reactions $A+B \rightarrow C+B$ have a similar rates to the straight reaction $A \rightarrow C$?

Comment: Since you named *Neuter Reactant*, it is up to you to describe the behavior that amkes it special. // More traditionally if B increase the reaction rate it is called a catalyst, and if B causes the reaction rate to be slower it is an inhibitor.

Comment: I meant it as a query to the community. I have learned that a Catalyst, for instance, is a substance that take part in the reaction but which is not consumed. Is there any substance that also takes part in a reaction and is not consumed but does not alter the kinetics of the reaction, like a catalyst or an inhibitor do. I don't know if such things exist and I am asking to see if anyone does, that is the question. Maybe I should edit the original question to make it more clear? What do you think?

Comment: If "B" is "consumed" it can't be on the right hand side of the equation.

Comment: Do you want it to take part in the reaction or not? I mean how can it take part without having any influence? That makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are reactions similar to the one you show, which is straightforward catalysis, these are autocatalytic reactions such as $\ce{A + B\to 2B}$ or $\ce{A + 3B\to 3B}$ which lead to interesting non-linear behaviour. Of more importance is the Michaelis-Menten scheme  $\ce{E + S\leftrightharpoons ES \to P + E}$ where E is an enzyme , S a substrate, ES a complex of both, and P the product.